# using JSP to read a file from the local file system

Tags: java, jsp, file-io

I need to read a file from the local file system using JSP, save it as a string , and send it to a webservice(deployed using glassfish) for processing. Can anyone suggest how to perform File IO using JSP?

Thanks,
Deepak.

Comment: Don't do that. JSP is a view layer technology, you should be doing things like File I/O in the servlet layer. Also, JSPs are not suitable for web services.

Comment: @skaffman: Doesn't affect the answer, though.

Comment: @TJ: I realise that, that's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @skaffman, TJ - JSPs are not suitable for web services? I need a web client for consuming SOAP based web services. What technologies would you advise? PHP, Perl? Because, i heard PHP doesn't have a good SOAP API, while i am not that great with Perl.

Comment: @Deepak: skaffman's being a purist (not necessarily a bad thing). Anything you can do in a servlet, you can do in a JSP (JSPs *are* servlets, in a way). But conceptually, JSPs are about rendering a result rather than building the result. Java's a great environment for building the server side of a web service. I'm not sure I understand your comment about needing "...a web *client* for consuming..." (my emphasis) and then asking about PHP and such. What you listed (PHP, Perl) are typically (though not exclusively) *server-side* technologies. Certainly JSPs and servlets are.

Comment: @TJ - I meant i need to write a web app that calls a SOAP based webservice.

Comment: @Deepak (continuing): Re client/server: So are you looking for something that runs on a server, but consumes a web service on another server? You can absolutely do that with Java (or PHP, or Perl). Re JSP/servlet: I'm not sure I was clear above. Basically, JSPs should be used for formatting your response, but they shouldn't be responsible for creating the response -- you want to do that in the classes they use, rather than in the JSP logic itself.

Comment: @Deepak: So in that situation, what I'd do is build classes around consuming the service and building the information I'm going to return to *my* client, and then I'd use JSPs to render the information from those classes. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing File I/O from a JSP is the same as doing it normally: Just use the [`java.io`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html) or [`java.nio`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) classes. If you need to map a virtual path to a real one, you can use [`ServletContext#getRealPath`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 1):

Technically, I tend to agree with T.J. here. But actually its not the same, its a bad idea altogether.

Comment: Why did you add `java-ee` tag to all `jsp`-tagged questions wherein you have answered? Please remove the `java-ee` tag. It's inappropriate in pretty much all of the questions which you retagged (and didn't retag yet, there are thousands of JSP/Servlet/JSF/JSTL/EL/JPA/etc questions without `java-ee` tag). If you disagree, please open a topic at meta.stackoverflow.com to discuss the rationale behind this retagging.

Comment: @BalusC: I did it, because its all related to `java-ee`, apparently. JSP is a part of `JavaEE`, none the less. And if you notice there always been a `java` tag already. Which means its related to Java. But the question is SE or EE? So, I tend to make it clear that its EE. Hence, it would help people finding JSP question as well, when actually looking for JavaEE. In case you still find my argument lame. We can have opinion of other folks on that.

Comment: @BalusC: Right now reviewing `java-ee` tags, to see what kinda of question we got there, if not JSP. Then I will consider rolling back all, or at least where its not suitable. Thanks for your noticing. I believe, its good to review once before starting any discussion in order to make some reasonable argument. I hope you are okay with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload a file to the server and process it, then use a html form with  fileupload field and select the text file and submit the form . the file will be uploaded to the server where you can process it

http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/javaserver-pages/uploading-file-using-jsp.html